# Need to a Instantiate a prefab in canvas which is in another scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making an achievement system.I have to 2 scene in my game.The first  scene is my Main Menu and the other scene is my game scene. I have designed and coded the achievement system in the main menu scene and added a EarnCanvas to my game scene. EarnCanvas will display the achievement that the player has unlocked.

Code i have is only allowing me to link the achievements to a EarnCanvas on the Main Menu scene.i need help to modifier the code or link the two scene so that i can instantiate the unlocked achievement prefab in the EarnCanvas in the game Scene. At the moment no prefab is instantiated or displayed in the EarnCanvas when the player has unlocked an achievement.

Main Menu scene

achievement Manager script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class AchievementManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject achievementPraf;

    public Sprite[] sprites;

    private AchievementButton activeButton;

    public ScrollRect scrollRect;

    public GameObject achievementMenu;

    public GameObject visualAchievement;

    public Dictionary<string, Achievement> achievements = new Dictionary<string, Achievement>();

    public Sprite UnlockedSprite;

    private static AchievementManager instance;

    public static AchievementManager Instance
    {
        get { 
            if(instance == null)
            {
                instance = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<AchievementManager>();
            }
            return AchievementManager.instance; 
        }

    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        //remove before deploy
       //PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();

        activeButton = GameObject.Find("Streakbtn").GetComponent<AchievementButton>();
        CreateAchievement("Streak", "Press W", "Press W to unlock  this achievement", 5, 0);
        CreateAchievement("Streak", "Press R", "Press R to unlock  this achievement", 5, 0);
        CreateAchievement("Streak", "Press All Keys", "Press All Keys to unlock", 5, 0, new string[] { "Press W", "Press R" });


        foreach (GameObject achievementList in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("achievementList"))
        {
            achievementList.SetActive(false);
        }


        activeButton.click();

        achievementMenu.SetActive(false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            achievementMenu.SetActive(!achievementMenu.activeSelf);

        }

            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
            {
                EarnAchievemnent("Press W");
            }

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
            {
                EarnAchievemnent("Press R");
            }
    }



    public void EarnAchievemnent(string title)
    {
        if(achievements[title].EarnAchievement())
        {
        GameObject achievement = (GameObject) Instantiate(visualAchievement);
        StartCoroutine(HideAchievement(achievement));

 //this is where is its giving the parent the gameobject name to find
                SetAchievementInfo("EarnCanvas", achievement, title);


        }
    }

    public IEnumerator HideAchievement(GameObject achievement)
    {

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);

        Destroy(achievement);
    }


    public void CreateAchievement(string parent,string title,string description,int points,int spriteIndex,string[] dependencies = null)
    {
        GameObject achievement = (GameObject)Instantiate(achievementPraf);

        Achievement newAchievement = new Achievement(name, description, points, spriteIndex,achievement);

        achievements.Add(title, newAchievement);

        SetAchievementInfo(parent, achievement,title);

        if(dependencies != null)
        {
            foreach(string achievementTitle in dependencies)
            {
                Achievement dependency = achievements[achievementTitle];
                dependency.Child = title;
                newAchievement.AddDependency(dependency);

                //Dependency = Press Space <-- Child = Press W 
                //NewAchievement = Press W --> Press Space
            }
        }
    }


    public void SetAchievementInfo(string parent, GameObject achievement, string title)
    {
        //this where its trying to find a gameobject-(EarnCanvas) to instantiate the unlocked achievement prefab in the Main Menu Scene
        achievement.transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find(parent).transform);
        achievement.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        achievement.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        achievement.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = title;
        achievement.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<Text>().text = achievements[title].Description;
        achievement.transform.GetChild(2).GetComponent<Text>().text = achievements[title].Points.ToString();
        achievement.transform.GetChild(3).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = sprites[achievements[title].SprintIndex];
    }

    public void ChangeCategory(GameObject button)
    {
        AchievementButton achievementButton = button.GetComponent<AchievementButton>();

        scrollRect.content = achievementButton.achievementList.GetComponent<RectTransform>();

        achievementButton.click();
        activeButton.click();

        activeButton = achievementButton;


    }
}
```

Main Menu Scene

Achievement Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class Achievement 
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    private string description;

    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set { description = value; }
    }

    private bool unlocked;

    public bool Unlocked
    {
        get { return unlocked; }
        set { unlocked = value; }
    }

    private int points;

    public int Points
    {
        get { return points; }
        set { points = value; }
    }

    private int sprintIndex;

    public int SprintIndex
    {
        get { return sprintIndex; }
        set { sprintIndex = value; }
    }

    private GameObject achievementRef;

    private List<Achievement> dependencies = new List<Achievement>();

    private string child;

    public string Child
    {
        get { return child; }
        set { child = value; }
    }

    public Achievement(string name,string description, int points, int sprintIndex, GameObject achievementRef)
    {

        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.unlocked = false;
        this.points = points;
        this.sprintIndex = sprintIndex;
        this.achievementRef = achievementRef;

        LoadAchievement();
    }

    public void AddDependency(Achievement dependency)
    {
        dependencies.Add(dependency);

    }
    public bool EarnAchievement()
    {
        if(!unlocked && !dependencies.Exists(x=> x.unlocked == false))
        {
            achievementRef.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = AchievementManager.Instance.UnlockedSprite;
            SaveAchievement(true);

            if(child != null)
            {
                AchievementManager.Instance.EarnAchievemnent(child);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void SaveAchievement(bool value)
    {
         unlocked = value;

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(name,value? 1 : 0);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

    public void LoadAchievement()
    {
        unlocked = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(name) == 1 ? true : false;

        if (unlocked)
        {
            achievementRef.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = AchievementManager.Instance.UnlockedSprite;
        }
    }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **DontDestroyOnLoad** method it is very simple way to retain gameobjects over scene changes you just need to add following code to your AchievementManager.

```
 void Awake () 
 {
     DontDestroyOnLoad (transform.gameObject);
 }
```

You can add this for any gameObject which you do not want to be destroyed upon changing scene.

Comment: hi nain.im getting this error when the prefab trys to instantiate in the EarnCavas in Game Scene.

Comment: You should post your error as comment. i am having a look at it.

Comment: your achievementRef game object is being destroyed you should also add DontDestroyOnLoad for achivement class witch contain achievementRef.

Comment: make another awake method in the achievement class?

Comment: your achievement class is not derived by monobehaviour so awak will not work and you will not be able to apply this script to gameobject.

Comment: any idea how to write this code ,since achievement class is not derived by monobehaviour?

Comment: your actual problem is with achievementPraf in achievmentmanager in the awake function of your achievmentmanager you can try this DontDestroyOnLoad (achievementPraf); and let me know if it solves the problem.

Comment: it worked but i am getting this error now.                      KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,Achievement].get_Item (System.String key) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:150)
AchievementManager.EarnAchievemnent (System.String title) (at Assets/Scripts/AchievementManager/AchievementManager.cs:89)
AchievementManager.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/AchievementManager/AchievementManager.cs:83)

Comment: when i press the m key the prefab appears ,then when i press the n key nothing appears

Comment: I think this solves your problem you have mentioned in your question. the error you are now getting is about accessing an item of dictionary which is not present in the dictionary so make sure you have the item in dictionary.

Comment: And If this solves your problem kindly mark this as an answer.

Comment: hi nain..i still have the same problem..when i go back to the main menu scene to view what i unlocked.it is still showing me those achievements as locked..sorry for taking so look to get back to you.what u told me to do is not working

Comment: is there anything else that i can do?